# How to update existing ElasticBeanstalk tomcat environment to 8.5

Tags: tomcat, elastic-beanstalk

I have an old EBS environment, running Tomcat 8.0. I want to update to 8.5, since it's the new one and 8.0 is no longer supported. How can I do that? The upgrade button just let me update the AMI to 3.x, but doesn't offer to upgrade Tomcat.

Comment: I thought that new AMI will contain new version of Tomcat. Isn't it?

Comment: I thought so too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new environment, deploy app to this env and after this swap environment addresses, Procedure is described in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.platform.upgrade.html#using-features.platform.upgrade.cross-config)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, AWS hasn't got around to advertising it, but you can actually migrate an existing instance to a new platform using the CLI.

Find your [solution stack name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.java).

Then update using the CLI (I've included an example stack name):

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name <YOUR-ELB-NAME> --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v4.0.1 running Tomcat 8.5 Corretto 11"
```